# NGINX location matching exact URL

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    set $base_root /var/www/test;
    root $base_root;

    access_log  /var/www/test/frontend/runtime/log/access.log;
    error_log   /var/www/test/frontend/runtime/log/error.log;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M; ## listen for ipv4

    client_body_buffer_size     32k;
    client_header_buffer_size   8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;

    index index.php index.html;

    set $_bootstrap "index.php";

    location / {
    
        root $base_root/frontend/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/web/index.php$is_args$args;
        
        location ~ ^/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }
        
    }

    location /cabinet/ {
        alias $base_root/app/;
        index    index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$args;
                
             
    }
}
```

I want everything that starts with "/cabinet/", opens app/index.html
"app" is a directory /var/www/test/app

if i wrote /cabinet/ it works, but if /cabinet/test it doesn't, it matches "location /"

Comment: Try using `/cabinet/index.html`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a lot! You saved my life.
But i can't understand why does this fix works?

Comment: The last parameter of a `try_files` directive is a URI and causes an internal redirection. The URI `/index.html` is handled by the `location /` block.